# Wouldn't each addition take time $O(n)$?

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

I am going over the asymptotic runtime of regular matrix multiplication.

Here  is a lecture slide I am referencing(too much to type out, shown below), from  [Algorithms](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~mdinitz/IntroAlgorithms/Lectures/lecture1.pdf) [image]

Everything makes sense up until the point that the author states that "each addition takes $O(n^2)$ time". Can anyone explain that?

I have a counter example here. Say I have a 4 by 4 matrix. The product of $A$ and $E$ would result in something like (2 by 2 matrix) $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 \\
        3 & 4  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$ and the product of $B$ and $G$ would result in something like $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
The author argues that one addition runs in $O(n^2)$ but I argue that one addition runs in $O(n)$. Here to add $AE$ and $BG$, you perform additions 1 + 5, 2 + 6, 3 + 7, and 4 + 8, or 4 additions. 4 was the original n, so the runtime of one addition would be $O(n)$

Do you guys agree with my counterexample/argument or did I miss something and runtime of one addition would be $O(n^2)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your matrix is a $2 \times 2$ matrix, which has $2^2=4$ entries. In your example your $n=2$ and $n^2 = 4$.

Adding two $n \times n$ matrices (which have $n^2$ entries) scale as $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$, since you would need to add $n^2$ entries of the first matrix with the $n^2$ entries of the second matrix.

Answer (score 4):

$AE$ and $BG$ are each submatrices of size $\frac{1}{2}n \times \frac{1}{2}n$. Hence, each submatrix has $\frac{1}{4}n^2$ entries. Thus, $AE + BG$ requires $\frac{1}{4}n^2 \in \mathcal O(n^2)$ additions. The problem in your small example is that half of $4$, then squared, coincidentally equals $4$.

Answer (score 3):

To reconcile this with the general case, note that each block matrix addition adds two matrices of dimension $\frac{n}{2} \times \frac{n}{2}$, so of $\frac{n^2}{4}$ elements, which is the complexity claimed (as constants don't matter). In your case, it happens to be that $$4 = n = \frac{n^2}{4} = \frac{16}{4} = 4$$

Generally, though, be careful with low-dimensional counter examples to asymptotic results.